# In foxpro is there a function to extract just numbers from a string or variable?

Tags: foxpro

In foxpro is there a function to extract just numbers from a string or variable?  Haven't found so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in function. I think you'll need to write a method to loop through your string and use **ISDIGIT()** to extract your numbers.

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap CHRTRAN functions and get the result in a single line of code.  For example:

```
* This can contain numbers, characters, special characters, etc.
m.lcSource = "ABC.1def23-gHI45J!#6KL"

* This is what I want returned back to me.  In this case, it's digits only.
m.lcReturnToMe = "0123456789"

* The inner CHRTRAN() function removes anything that is a number.  The return value is
* what will be removed in the outer CHRTRAN function.
m.lcDigitsOnly = CHRTRAN(m.lcSource, CHRTRAN(m.lcSource, m.lcReturnToMe, SPACE(0)), SPACE(0))
```

Comment: This is a technique I've used since forever to also strip out invalid characters from data entry fields....

Comment: +1 for this. I thought about it, but isn't this limited to v7 and up?

Comment: @Beaner I ran this code in FoxPro DOS 2.6 and Visual FoxPro 9.  I'll assume it works with everything in between. <grin>

Answer (score 1):

```
returnstring=''
for i=1 to =len(stringname)
    if isdigit(substr(stringname,i,1))
        returnstring=returnstring+substr(stringname,i,1)
    endif
endfor

?returnstring
```